# Add UDH for concatenated Unicode SMS

Tags: unicode, sms, gsm, modem, pdu

[This](http://mobiletidings.com/2009/02/18/combining-sms-messages/)
is the link I learned to send multi-part SMS in PDU, a very good tutorial.But how if I want to send Unicode SMS? From one of the comment from the developer:

> Yes, the DCS should be `0×08` and the UDL should be in octets (which ends up being 1 + UDHL + 2 * number of characters). Also you don’t have to insert padding as in the GSM-7 case. I know you’ve already managed to send UCS-2 (not concatenated) messages, so it must be something small you’re missing. If you wish you can post your PDUs so I can check…
>
> Jeroen

it seems I do not need to add 1 bit padding for the message. But if I using the same UDH format as normal SMS it will just show me unknown characters.
Can anyone give me some hints?

This is the sample PDU with chinese character but should be with errors..

`0041000B910661345542F60000A00500030302010008044F60597D`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DCS is wrong.

0041000B910661345542F6000**0**A00500030302010008044F60597D

should be

0041000B910661345542F6000**8**A00500030302010008044F60597D

for a DCS of 0x08 = UCS-2 encoding.

Comment: Thank you so much Vicky , now it works . A sample PDU with no error : 0041010C910661345542F60008A0050003000301306F3044

Thanks again.