# How to send Multi-part unicoded SMS using At Commands And PDU-Submit Not with Text-Mode?

Tags: c#, unicode, sms, gsm, at-command

In my project, I want to send a unicoded text(UTF-8) SMS message through PDU-Submit. I've been searching a lot but all answers using Text-Mode and not PDU-Submit command, therefore I can't send multipart SMS. I want to have a solution for multi-part unicode messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have found the answer and use it.my program works fine. Sending a Concatenated(Multi-Part) SMS in Unicode Format Using PDU, is the same sending a simple septet-character SMS using AT+CMGS Command except you must set the DCS byte to 08.You can earn more Info on these threads:

[Add UDH for concatenated Unicode SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114456/add-udh-for-concatenated-unicode-sms)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS#PDU_Mode_SMS

Comment: is it possible to send multipart sms in text mode i.e  `AT+CMGF=1"

Answer (score 2):

You can send SMS messages with the `AT+CMGS` command in PDU mode (enable with `AT+CMGF=0`). The [syntax](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) (for pdu mode) is

```
AT+CMGS=<length><CR>
PDU is given<ctrl-Z/ESC>
```

I do not know if you are supposed to split into multipart yourself and send each part separately or if this command does that for you. I think maybe the latter, the description of the command says

> Execution command sends message from a TE to the network (SMS-SUBMIT).

If/when you find out, feel free to update this answer with regards to that.

Comment: Dear hlovdal,thanks for your respond, I have found that, bellow is my answer.